# Azure SQL DB with AAD - is there a way to get read-only access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am looking for a way to sign in into Azure SQL DB with my AAD credentials, but I only want to have read-only access.

**First try**

- Opened Azure SQL Server Access Control (IAM) tab.
- Added myself a `Managed Applications Reader` role.
- This doesn't allow me to connecto to the DB with the following error.

```
Cannot connect to abc.database.windows.net.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
------------------------------

AADSTS900021: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid.
Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.
Trace ID: xxx
Correlation ID: yyy
Timestamp: 2020-04-09 08:57:20Z (System.Data)
```

**Second try**

- Opened Azure SQL Server Active Directory Admin.
- Added myself as an admin.
- This allows me to connect now with AAD credentials, but I have all the permissions I am scared to have on a prod DB now.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to assign another user as SQL AAD admin.
Login as that user, and run:

```
CREATE USER [your.user@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','your.user@domain.com';
```

This will create a contained user in the database for your AAD user, and assign the data reader role to them.
You can also grant read access to single tables etc. with standard T-SQL.

Comment: I assume I don't need to create an AAD admin, instead I should be able to use an ordinary admin user for these queries?

Comment: At least in the past I found they did not work with a regular SQL admin. If it works then of course you can do that :)

Comment: You are right, I am getting `Principal 'abc@xyz.com' could not be created. Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.`

Comment: I'm guessing they query the AAD tenant behind the scenes on your behalf. This means you need to login through AAD, and with a user that has access to the users/groups/apps being added.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, thanks. I am getting `Principal 'abc@xyz.com' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.` Any ideas why?